# Proving the uniform convergence of the average sequence of $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I was asked to prove that:

1) $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)$ does not converge pointwise.

2) The average sequence of $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)$ is uniformly convergent.

I secceed to prove the first part but I cannot prove the other one. In addition it is not allowed to use the M-test.

Thanks. (I do not know how to use the function signs.)

Comment: I expect the only property of $\sin(x)$ you will need is that it has an irrational period. The average will converge to the integral over the period.

Comment: I forgot to mention pi/3=>x>=2pi/3 . can you explain how it helps?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{ikx}=\frac{e^{inx}-1}{n(e^{ix}-1)}.$$

Comment: I think you mean $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}e^{inx}$.

Comment: We do not use complex numbers at our solutions..

Comment: You can use Euler's formula to get back $\sin$ and $\cos$. The solution Yves is hinting at is a really neat use of complex numbers.

Comment: I think you do need an edge case for $x=2k\pi$ by the way.

Comment: I can not see how it helps yet... another hint can help.

Comment: @SmileyCraft: oops, I made it ambiguous by using the index $i$. Fixed. And yes, there is an edge case (which is simple to handle).

Comment: @DANIELSHALAM: it helps by showing that the partial sums equal $\dfrac{f(x)}n$ for some function $f$.

Comment: I know what your mean but that not the partial sum of the average sequence so i dont see how it helps.

Comment: @DANIELSHALAM: have you considered the imaginary part ?

Comment: With no succses..